Сортировка методом "sorted" по дате убывания
Всем доброго времени суток!
У меня две отдельных таблицы с постами. У них есть одинаковое поле "pub_date", в котором указана дата публикации. Мне нужно отсортировать посты из двух таблиц по дате убывания. Делаю методом 'sorted'.
Проблема в том, что сначала отображаются посты по дате убывания из одной таблицы, а потом из другой.
Подскажите, как сделать так, что бы посты отображались по дате убывания из двух таблиц между собой?
Вот мой код:
Views.py
def index(request):
     post = Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
     blog = Blog.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
     posts = sorted((chain(post, blog)), key=attrgetter('pub_date'))
     context= {
         'posts':posts,
     }
     return render(request, 'content/index.html', context)'

HTML
<div class="block3">
    <h1 class="h3">Новые публикации</h1>
    <div class="block4">
      <div class="blog-slider_wrapper">
        <div class="blog-slider">
          <div class="blog-slider__wrp swiper-wrapper">
            {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="blog-slider__item swiper-slide">
              
              <div class="blog-slider__img">
                {% if post.preview %}
                  {% thumbnail post.preview "300x300" as im %}
                    <img src="//img.youtube.com/vi/{{post.preview}}/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
                  {% endthumbnail %}
                {% else %}
                  {% thumbnail post.image "300x300" as im %}
                    <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="">
                  {% endthumbnail %}
                {% endif %}
              </div>
              <div class="blog-slider__content">
                <span class="blog-slider__date">{{post.pub_date|date:"d E Y"}}</span>
                <div class="blog-slider__title">{{post.title}}</div>
                {% if post.text_b %}
                  <p>{{post.text_b|truncatewords:75}}</p>
                {% else %}
                  <p>{{post.text|truncatewords:75}}</p>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="blog-slider__button-wrapper">
                  {% if post.text_b %}
                  <a href="{% url 'content:menu' post.id %}" class="blog-slider__button">Читать далее</a>
                  {% else %}
                  <a href="{% url 'content:news_post' post.id %}" class="blog-slider__button">Читать далее</a>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
          <div class="blog-slider__pagination"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>'


Если под «отображаются» вы имеете в виду результат рендеринга шаблона, то какой код у шаблона-то?

Добавил шаблон .......

Что-то при таких вводных непонятно, как описанная проблема может случиться

Весь вопрос здесь в функции "Index", в ней происходит выборка из двух таблиц и сортировка по дате убывания

говорят, что правильно сформулированный вопрос - половина ответа

а если вместо Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5] попробовать Post.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5] ? то есть, вместо менеджера, отдавать queryset, как и должно быть по идее?

Такое впечатление, что в данном случае sorted ничего не сортирует вообще. Покажите, как выглядит любой элемент (хоть нулевой) из списка post. В частности, какой точно тип у поля pub_date.

strawdog:  вариант Post.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5] дал тоже самое

CrazyElf: что вы имеете ввиду, показать скриншот как это выглядит на странице, или показать код models.py ?
